# Azure Digital Twin ADT Explorer - Multiple Rooms

Tags: azure-digital-twins

Setup ADT Explorer and Sample Floor & Room using this tutorial
[Digital Twin Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/tutorial-command-line-app)

In addition, added the additional rooms and created the relationship using these commands

```
CreateDigitalTwin dtmi:example:Room;2 room01 RoomName string Room01 Temperature double 70 HumidityLevel double 30
CreateDigitalTwin dtmi:example:Room;2 room02 RoomName string Room02 Temperature double 70 HumidityLevel double 30

CreateRelationship floor0 contains room01 relationship01
CreateRelationship floor0 contains room02 relationship02
```

When I run the query "`SELECT floor, room FROM DIGITALTWINS floor JOIN room RELATED floor.contains where floor.$dtId = 'floor0'`", I can see only the relation between floor0 and room0 and not with room01 and room02.

[image]

Any suggestions please.

Comment: In the SampleClientApp that you used to create the models, could you run:
`Query SELECT floor, room FROM DIGITALTWINS floor JOIN room RELATED floor.contains where floor.$dtId = 'floor0'` and verify the correct relationships are there? I'm following your steps, but my ADT explorer shows the result correctly.

Comment: It looks like some temporary cache issue. I ran SetupBuildingScenario after that, it showed relationship between room21 and thermostat67 and no relation is shown for floor1 with room1. Now it shows proper relationships. Thanks for checking the issue. I will update here if the issue persists.

Comment: @Harish Add the above comment as answer and accept so that it will be beneficial to the community as well.